# Kendo Gantt change column values

Tags: javascript, jquery, typescript, kendo-ui, kendo-gantt

I use Kendo UI for jQuery - Gantt widget. The data model contains two fields (Value1 and Value2). How can I use a radio-button to switch the display of a value in a column from Value1 to Value2 and backwards (without resending requests to the server)? And how to first initialize columns depending on the parameter (what value to display in the column)?

```
public MyData {
  Id: number;
  PeriodStart: date;
  PeriodEnd: date;
  Value1: string;
  Value2: string;
}

$("#myGantt").kendoGantt({
  toolbar: [
    { template: kendo.template($("#MyTemplate").html()) }
  ],
  columns: [
    { field: "Id", title: "Id" },
    { field: "start", title: "Date begin" },
    { field: "end", title: "Date end" },
    { field: "TODO", title: "Value1 or Value2", width: 100 }
  ],
  ...
});

<script id="MyTemplate" type="text/x-kendo-template">
  <div>
    <div id="ganttRadioGroup">
      <label><input type="radio" name="nameGantt" id="name1" value="1" checked>Value 1</label>
      <label><input type="radio" name="nameGantt" id="name2" value="2">Value 2</label>
    </div>    
  </div>
</script>
<div id="myGantt"></div>
```

How to switch value?

```
$("#ganttRadioGroup input").on("change", function () {
  let selectedRadioValue = $("input[name=nameGantt]:checked", "#ganttRadioGroup").val();
  // TODO
}
```

Comment: Make both columns in Kendo and hide one via JS?

Comment: I ended up doing this: _let data = $("#myGantt").data("kendoGantt").dataSource.data();_ and _data.forEach..._ with _item.set..._ by condition.